# Excel: Applying dynamic array function UNIQUE in excel to a table with rows & columns >1

Tags: excel, filter, unique, dynamic-arrays

I have a survey of rents in the table called "Rent Survey Data" which is defined as a name "TBL_RentSurvey".

[image: This table is defined as "TBL_RentSurvey]

I use the new dynamic array function "FILTER" to output data that is filtered with various AND/OR criteria according to the fields: W/D, Attchd Garage, SS Appliances, Den, Rehab, and a start/end date. Note that "*" operator refers to AND and "+" operator refers to OR. I have 2 rows for my filter because sometimes I would like to output various combinations of 1 criteria and hence use the "+" operator.

When I apply the UNIQUE function (also a new dynamic array function), I do not get a unique array outputted.  You can see that Vizcaya is outputted twice.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.  I was expecting to have a unique table based on all of those arguments.

[image]

You can see below that Vizcaya was outputted twice.  I'm not sure why.

[image]

I was expecting this output:

[image]

Code for the two scenarios:

```
((TBL_RentSurvey[W/D]=C4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[W/D]=C5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[Attchd Garage]=D4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[Attchd Garage]=D5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[SS Appliances]=E4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[SS Appliances]=E5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[Den]=F4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[Den]=F5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[Rehab]=G4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[Rehab]=G5))
*(TBL_RentSurvey[Unit Type]=H4)
*(TBL_RentSurvey[[Date ]]>=L4)
*(TBL_RentSurvey[[Date ]]<=L5))



=UNIQUE(FILTER(TBL_RentSurvey[[Property]:[Unit Type]],
((TBL_RentSurvey[W/D]=C4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[W/D]=C5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[Attchd Garage]=D4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[Attchd Garage]=D5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[SS Appliances]=E4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[SS Appliances]=E5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[Den]=F4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[Den]=F5))
*((TBL_RentSurvey[Rehab]=G4)+(TBL_RentSurvey[Rehab]=G5))
*(TBL_RentSurvey[Unit Type]=H4)
*(TBL_RentSurvey[[Date ]]>=L4)
*(TBL_RentSurvey[[Date ]]<=L5)))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that one of the numbers are not text that looks like numbers, also check to ensure that there is no decimal that the format is not showing.

Comment: In your original table, it seems that `SS Appliances` is listed as `0` for one of the `Vizcaya` and blank for the other.  Depending on what's going on behind the scenes, it is likely that what you think is identical, is not.